# Show me the value of all my US *and* French bank/brokerage accounts

Tags: finance

I am looking for a program or web-based service that can show me the value of all my different US *and* French bank/brokerage accounts, and give me the sum of it (e.g, "X USD").

No preference regarding the license, the cost or the operating system.

---

What I have found so far:

- https://www.mint.com/ and https://www.personalcapital.com/ only support US bank/brokerage accounts.
- https://bankin.com/ and https://www.linxo.com/en/ only support FR bank/brokerage accounts.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that you haven't been able to find a program or service that does what you want because the legal requirements for software accessing bank data are different between the US and France?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin no because plenty of websites are dealing with multiple different local laws and regulations. But I agree that doesn't help indeed.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should put all the eggs in the same basket.

For example [Swissquote](https://en.swissquote.com/) or [Degiro](https://www.degiro.eu/) can allow you to do so but you have to move all your bank/brokerage to their accounts.

Once they are there you can have an overview of it and the sum of it in USD, EUR, CHF, NZD, etc...

Comment: Thanks, I wish but not all baskets are the same due to tax laws + bank fees + market access.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, I use Swissquote both for banking and trading. You can trade all over the World, any market any currency, and the right fees are applied: https://en.swissquote.com/trading/pricing/stocks (in the examples there are just 6 columns but rest assured you have all the 60 markets and the relative fee is shown before you buy the stocks)

Comment: Thanks. Can they handle country-specific account types such as PEA, PEL, IRA, 401(k), HSA, Livret A, etc.? Likely not.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, that is a very specific question. In this case I suppose the answer is no. But I also suppose that there is no app around the world that could help you archive that. But I have the same problem as you do, having my savings between Switzerland and New Zealand and lately I stumble upon Sharesight.com https://www.wealthmorning.com/2019/09/26/627889/a-one-stop-solution-how-to-track-your-investments/ I'm testing it but I cannot tell yet if that is the silver bullet for people like us

Comment: Otherwise what we need is dashboard like https://simplywall.st/portfolio/my-portfolios where we can upload manually our data. But then you have to manually update the portfolio and that sucks

Answer (score 0):

My answer is that it sounds like a great app to develop! The competition must be lagging behind your requirements, opening the door to a new market. The concept has been explored successfully with these apps but isn't working out as planned, so improving it might be a winning design.

We would need a few things first: a business plan, a prototype, and the opinions of experienced developers.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/61640)